# Apple TV unable to turn soundbar on/off

Tags: audio, bluetooth, appletv

I have a LG SJ2 soundbar connected to a Sharp Aquos lc-32hi3012e TV via 3.5mm jack from the TVs headphone out and while I can adjust the volume using the remote of my Apple TV 4K powering it on and off together with Apple TV and TV doesn’t work. My Amazon Fire TV Stick could be trained to do this yet I do not find an option besides volume with the Apple TV.

I will get an optical cable to connect the soundbar to the TV but I doubt this’ll change anything.

It doesn’t have hdmi but pairing the bar with the ATV via Bluetooth doesn’t work. I get an error. It pairs with my iPhone just fine tho.

ATV OS is up to date.

Comment: Its always helpful to give exact model numbers of all equipment involved in troubleshooting, not to mention OS versions of Apple hardware. I you would kindly edit your original question and add that info.